# Grab more than 2 parameters using RewriteCond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL with 4 query parameters:
`https://address.com/bin/servlet?firstKey=firstValue&secondKey=secondValue&thirdKey=thirdValue`
I would to map this URL to path variables:
`https://address.com/content/firstValue/secondValue/thirdValue`

This is what I'm trying to do:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &?firstKey=([^&]+)&?secondKey=([^&]+) [NC]`
Then rewriting rule:
`RewriteRule ^/bin/servlet /content/%1/%2 [QSD,PT]`
This is working fine.
**But the pain is:** Third parameter, when I'm adding 3rd key like other 2 parameters it won't work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &?firstKey=([^&]+)&?secondKey=([^&]+)&?thirdKey=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/bin/servlet /content/%1/%2/%3 [QSD,PT]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your implementation, for example the usage of "&" in the condition. But in general there is no limit to the number of parameters you can detect and handle with your chose strategy.

I made a few adjustments, this probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^firstKey=([^&]+)&secondKey=([^&]+)&thirdKey=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^/?bin/servlet$ /content/%1/%2/%3 [R=301,QSD,L]

RewriteRule ^/?content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /bin/servlet?firstKey=$1&secondKey=$2&thirdKey=$3 [L,QSA]
```

This obviously only handles requests using exactly *three* parameters. It is possible to generalize such approach to be able to handle a dynamic number of parameters, but I would advise against it: often it is better to keep things less complex, so just add corresponding rules for 2 and 4 parameters, if required. That way you will be able to maintain and extend the solution easily.

---

UPDATE:

In your comment below you ask if it is possible to capture argument values specified in arbitrary order. Sure, everything is possible, but things get a bit more complex then. Take a look at this example:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)firstKey=([^&]+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?bin/servlet$ - [E=FIRST_VAL:%1]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)secondKey=([^&]+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?bin/servlet$ - [E=SECOND_VAL:%1]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)thirdKey=([^&]+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?bin/servlet$ - [E=THIRD_VAL:%1]
RewriteRule ^/?bin/servlet$ /content/%{ENV:FIRST_VAL}/%{ENV:SECOND_VAL}/%{ENV:THIRD_VAL} [R=301,QSD,L]

RewriteRule ^/?content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /bin/servlet?firstKey=$1&secondKey=$2&thirdKey=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes you are right it's better to keep things simple. Just the issue is that if user change the order of the query rule will break. How we can do it unordered?